# Tuple Function (return values) in C#

Tags: winforms, function, tuples

If you have the following function, for example:

```
public Tuple<int, int> GetMultipleValue()
{
     return Tuple.Create(1,2);
}
```

How would you access those integers in your main program, after calling `GetMultipleValue()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tuple classes have properties with very "logical" names: `Item1`, `Item2`, `Item3`, ...

```
Tuple<int, int> temp = GetMultipleValue();
Console.WriteLine("{0}; {1};", temp.Item1.ToString(), temp.Item2.ToString());
```

From MSDN [`Tuple <T1, T2> Class`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @John, If this is the answer you were looking for,you should accept it. Give credit where it's due, and increase your odds of getting helpful answers in the future.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you would save your return value into a tuple object. For example

```
var myTuple = GetMultipleValue()
```

And then you can access the individual parts of the tuple by

```
myTuple.Item1
```

or

```
myTuple.Item2
```